# Travers through Neo4j nodes and relationships in JAVA using REST API

Tags: java, rest, neo4j

I want to traverse through Neo4j database nodes and relationships in java (not the embedded one. I want to use REST API).
I have following method.

```
public void testTraverse(Node startNode) {
        for (Path position : Traversal.description()
                .depthFirst()
                .uniqueness(Uniqueness.NODE_GLOBAL)
                .evaluator(Evaluators.toDepth(10)).traverse(startNode)) 
        {
            System.out.println(position.lastRelationship().toString()+"\n--------------------------------\n");
        }
        for(Node node:Traversal.description().traverse(startNode).nodes()) {
            System.out.println(node.getProperty("name"));
        }
}
```

When calling this method, how I can create that startNode of type Node, which I want to pass as the parameter?

I am very new to Neo4j.
Please help me.
Alternative methods for Neo4j-Java-ReST is also warm welcomed...

Comment: Don't use traverse on the Node but create a `RestTraversalDescription` to describe your traversal and then pass in the nodes to `traverse` for it to be executed on the server.

Comment: Hi @Micheal Hunger, is this the way u mean, ..> new RestAPIFacade("http://localhost:7474/db/data").createTraversalDescription()..relationships(RELATIONSHIPTYPES.X,Direction.OUTGOING).breadthFirst().evaluator(Evaluators.atDepth(2))    .traverse(nodesList.toArray(new Node[0]))  .. This returns a org.neo4j.graphdb.traversal.Traverser, is that right ? If not can you put the line for your above comment "create a RestTraversalDescription to describe your traversal and then pass in the nodes to traverse" . Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Well, that starting node would have to be a node that you previously stored somehow.

Via the `GraphDatabaseService` instance, you could look up a node either by its ID:

```
Node yourNode = graphDatabaseService.getNodeById(0L);
```

...or through an index:

```
Node yourNode = graphDatabaseService.forNodes("anIndexName").get("id", 42).getSingle();
```

Comment: Or you create your nodes and relationships by using the APIs like `graphDatabase.createNode()` or `restApi.createNode(params)` or with a cypher statement.